# How to find nearest number in a sequence that is strictly smaller than given number

Tags: algorithms

Given a sequence of numbers $l_1, \ldots, l_k$, I want to find for each $i$ the nearest numbers to the left and right of $l_i$ (if any) that are strictly smaller than $l_i$. Is it possible to do this in linear time?

Comment: No, the problem is essentially equivalent to sorting, so it cannot in O(k)

Comment: @jmster Care to elaborate?

Comment: @jmster I am reading the paper here: http://eprints.library.iisc.ernet.in/60/1/COLE.pdf and in section 8 paragraph 4, it talks about something like what i am trying to do. Of course the scenario in the paper is a bit different but it seems like you would still need to be able to solve this problem inlinear time

Comment: What does nearest mean? $l_j \lt l_i$ such that $|i - j|$ is smallest or $|l_i - l_j|$ is smallest? If the former, there is a linear time algorithm.

Comment: @Aryabhata I meant the former. Can you explain the linear time algorithm?

Comment: Traverse left to right, push stuff on stack if new element >= top element. If new element < top element keep popping the stack till top < new element. For the elements popped, the new element is the $l_j$.

Comment: @Aryabhata ahhh i see. Would you mind posting a full answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment into an answer.

Here is an algorithm for the interpretation that you are looking for $l_j$ such that $l_j \lt l_i$ and $|i-j|$ is the smallest.

> Traverse left to right, push stuff on stack. If new element to be pushed >= top
>   element. If new element < top element keep popping the stack till top
>   < new element. For the elements popped, the new element is the $l_j$